# MVC EditorFor bind to type in array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that, among other properties, contains an array of 'EmailAddress' objects.  EmailAddress itself has properties such as "Address", and "IsPrimary".  My view model breakdown is:

```
public class UserDetailsViewModel {
  public BUser User { get; set; }
  public string[] Roles { get; set; }
  public EmailAddress[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

I am showing a "User Details" page that is pretty standard.  For example, I'm displaying data using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.UserName)` and `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Comment)`  I also have a section on the page that lists all of the EmailAddress objects associated with the user:

```
@if(Model.EmailAddresses.Length > 0) {
  foreach (var address in Model.EmailAddresses) {
    <div>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => address.Address)
    </div>
  }
} else {
  <div class="center">User does not have any email addresses.</div>
}
```

My problem is that I would like to show an "Add Email Address" form above the list of email addresses.  I thought I would take the "normal" approach thusly:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(new { id=Model.User.UserName, action="AddUserEmailAddress" })) {    
  <text>Address:</text> @Html.EditorFor(model => ** HERE I AM STUCK **)
  <input type="submit" value="Add Email" class="button" />
}
```

As you may be able to tell, I am stuck here.  I've tried `model => Model.EmailAddresses[0]` and `model => Model.EmailAddresses.FirstOrDefault()`.  Both of these have failed horribly.

I am sure that I am going about this all wrong.  I've even thought of adding a "dummy" property to my ViewModel of type EmailAddress just so that I can bind to that in my EditorFor - but that seems to be a really bad hack.  There has to be something simple that I'm overlooking!

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer with this matter.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the quick&dirty way of using :

```
@Html.TextBox("NewEmail")
```

In your AddUserEmailAddress controller method you will be able to get the posted value by using :

```
Request.Form.GetValues("NewEmail")
```

or

```
Request["NewEmail"]
```

If you don't want to loose the built in validation, as you stated, you can always create another property in your ViewModel ? 
Supply your view with a form, or load it dynamically with jQuery.load("/Controller/AddEmail/UserID"). Add

```
public string NewEmail { get; set; }
```

in your ViewModel, and the below in your view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.NewEmail)
```

Plus, you may consider using strongly typed structure for your emails like List that gives you more control over your data in particular situations.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I don't get the automatic model validation (both client and server side).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to MVC, but I've already tackled this problem, I use `@Html.Partial` for that.

```
@Html.Partial("path/to/EditorTemplate", new EmailAddress())
```

I also tried to take the `EmailAddresses[0]` route, I remember that day fondly.
I'm also not positive it is the best way, but it plays nicely with my other code.